# Codility PermCheck Solution isn't working on a few data sets

Tags: java, algorithm

Trying to solve codility lessons for practice and working on [this](https://codility.com/programmers/task/perm_check).

Written my code in Java and tested the code on a wide range of inputs, however the code fails for extreme_min_max, single and double in the codility test results.

Assumption given:

N is an integer within the range `[1..100,000]`.
Each element of array A is an integer within the range `[1..1,000,000,000]`.

Explanation of my code:
1. Sort the given array.
2. Iterate over each element in the array to find the difference between every consecutive pair. If the difference is not 1, Then its not a perm hence return 0. In case there is only one element in the array, return 1.

Can anyone please help me find out the bug(s) in my code?

My code:

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{
    if(A.length == 1)
        return 1;

    Arrays.sort(A);
    for (int i = 0; i < A.length-1; i++)
    {
        long diff = Math.abs(A[i] - A[i+1]);
        if(diff!=1)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I think you algorithm is wrong to begin with. Your code checks that the difference between consecutive places is no bigger than one, but you need to check that all number  `[1, n]` are in the array. For example, `[3, 2, 1]` will fail for you, but `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]` will not...

Comment: "If the difference is not 1, Then its not a perm hence return 0. In case there is only one element in the array, return 1." - This is incorrect. Find another way to check that all number `[1, n]` are in the array

Comment: Hi, The code worked fine for both of these inputs because in the first set, the difference between every consecutive pair is always one and in the second, the array after sorting will bring all duplicates together. so the difference between the first pair itself will be zero.

Comment: But sort is not `O(n)`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple and better implementation which runs in `O(N)` time complexity and takes `O(N)` space complexity.

```
public int solution(int[] A)
{ 
    int size = A.length;
    int hashArray[] = new int[size+1];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(A[i]>size)
            return 0;
        else
            hashArray[A[i]]+=1;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=size;i++)
    if(hashArray[i]!=1)
    return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in C# (Score 100%) :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

class Solution {
   public int solution(int[] A) {

     if (A.Any(x => x == 0)) { return 0; }
         var orderSelect = A.OrderBy(x => x).GroupBy(x => x);
         if (orderSelect.Any(x => x.Count() > 1)) { return 0; }
         var res = Enumerable.Range(1, A.Length).Except(A);
         return res.Any() ? 0 : 1;           
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty simple:

Your code doesn't check this condition:

> A permutation is a sequence containing each element **from 1** to N once, and only once.

Ensure that the first element after sorting is 1, and everything should work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Well did you mean to say that i need to add    if(A[0] == 1)  before going forward with the for loop?

Comment: exactly. The definition of the permutation specifies that a permutation **must** start with 1, thus `if(A[0] != 1) return 0;`

Comment: It worked!. But it still failed for extreme_min_max inputs

Comment: @user1472018 what exactly do you mean by "extreme_min_max" inputs? and a little note concerning complexity: the time-complexity of any sorting-algorithm is `> O(n)`, so you'll have to use another approach

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big on Java syntax, but what you want to do here is:

1. Create an array `temp` the length of `A` - initialized to `0`.
2. Go over `A` and do `temp[A[i]]++`.
3. Go over `temp`, and if any place in the array is not `1`, return false.

Answer (score 0):

If duplicate exists - return 0 I have implemented with 100% pass
https://codility.com/demo/results/trainingWX2E92-ASF/

```
public static int permCheck(int A[]){

Set<Integer> bucket = new HashSet<Integer>();
int max = 0;
int sum=0;
for(int counter=0; counter<A.length; counter++){
    if(max<A[counter]) max=A[counter];
    if(bucket.add(A[counter])){
        sum=sum+A[counter];
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
System.out.println(max+"->"+sum);
int expectedSum = (max*(max+1))/2;
if(expectedSum==sum)return 1;

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first 100% code.
I can't say if it's the fastest but it seems all correct -- watch the double `OR` ( `||` ) condition.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution 
{
   public int solution(int[] A) 
   {

      int i = 0;
      int size = A.length;

      if ( size > 0 && size < 100001)
      {
          // Sort the array ascending:
          Arrays.sort(A);

          // Check each element:
          for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
             if ( A[i] > size || A[i] != (i + 1) )
                return 0;
          return 1;
      }
      return 0;
   }
}
```

**EDIT**
Actually, we need not worry about valid first element data (i.e. A[i] > 0) because, after sorting, a valid perm array must have A[0] = 1 and this is already covered by the condition A[i] = i + 1. 
The upper limit for array entries (> 1,000,000,000) is restricted further by the limit on the array size itself (100,000) and we must check for conformity here as there will be a Codility test for this. So I have removed the lower limit condition on array entries.

Answer (score 0):

Below code runs and gave me a 100%, the time complexity is O(n):

```
    private static int solution(int[] A) {
    int isPermutation = 1; // all permutations start at 1
    int n = A.length;
    Arrays.sort(A);

    if (n == 0) return 0; // takes care of edge case where an empty array is passed

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (A[i] != isPermutation) { //if current array item is not equals to permutation, return 0;
            return 0;
        }
        isPermutation++;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

100% score with complexity O(N)

```
 public int solution(int[] A) {
     int res = 1;
    
    if (A.length == 1 && A[0]!=1)
        return 0;
    
    int[] B = new int[A.length];
    for (int j : A) {
        int p = j - 1;
        if (A.length > p)
            B[p] = j;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < B.length - 1; i++) {
        if (B[i] + 1 != B[i + 1]) {
            res = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```